# How to add a class to a link if parent list item has children?

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I'm building Bootstrap menu in Kentico 6 using "Universal viewer" webpart and hierarchical transformations. So far I got the structure done, but I'm not able to figure out how to add "dropdown-menu" class to a link when his parent `<li>` has children.

This is the code I'm generating now:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Some link</a>
    <ul>...</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I'm trying to achieve this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Some link</a>
    <ul>...</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Class and data should be added only if parent `<li>` has `<ul>` embedded inside.

Should I use macro transformation or is there a way to achieve this with ascx transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there always is a dropdown in case of some child nodes you could use `NodeChildNodesCount` value.

```
<a href="#" <%# ((int)Eval("NodeChildNodesCount") > 0) ? "class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\"" : "" %>>Some link</a>
```

If there are some additional conditions like document type, you need to retrieve number of child nodes for that specific conditions. You can achieve it through document API, in a helper class or directly in ASCX transformation. Look for TreeProvider class. Note that this may be performance intensive operation. I would also consider adding that those dropdown classes on the client side by javascript.

Comment: Thanks @mivra, this worked! Do you mind extending your answer and showing example how to add this class only when child document is a "Page" menu item, or if it's easier when child documents "Show in navigation" is checked.